# System command output leaking - perl

Tags: perl, command, system, output

just starting to use Perl here. I previously have successfully used backticks to capture system command output in Perl, such as:

```
my @sysOut = `cleartool checkout -nc \"$file\"`; # works fine!
```

but I have run into some trouble, and even after looking around for some time I didn't find the solution to this problem. I am trying to write a Perl script to check in a list of checked out files `(@allfiles)` using cleartool, except if any are identical to their predecessor, then un-checkout them.

The way I am (...failing at!) detecting whether they are identical or not is to get the output from the check in attempt, see if it matches `/error.*identical/i`, and then if so uncheckout the file. However, for some reason the output seems to bypassing the array I am passing it into.
See code which generates this problem:

```
foreach my $file (@allfiles){ 
    chomp( my @checkInErr = `cleartool checkin -nc \"$file\"`);
    foreach my $err (@checkInErr) { # if no error, checkin done
        if ($err =~ m/error.*identical/i) {  # if there is error:
            print $err; 
            print "No change detected: unchecking out.\n"; # uncheckout same version
            system "cleartool uncheckout -rm -cact \"$file\""; 
        }
    } 
}
```

Here is my command line output (as if I had just used a system() call):

```
cleartool: Error: Unable to check in "a5TI.txt".
cleartool: Error: By default, won't create version with data identical to predecessor.
cleartool: Error: Unable to check in "a6cm.txt".
cleartool: Error: By default, won't create version with data identical to predecessor.
cleartool: Error: Unable to check in "a6FT.txt".
cleartool: Error: By default, won't create version with data identical to predecessor.
cleartool: Error: Unable to check in "a6pm.txt".
cleartool: Error: By default, won't create version with data identical to predecessor.
cleartool: Error: Unable to check in "a6TI.txt".
cleartool: Error: By default, won't create version with data identical to predecessor.
```

**SOLUTION:** check std error stream as well when grabbing output (in retrospect this makes sense as I was trying to parse error messages... oh well)

```
my @checkInErr = `cleartool checkin -nc \"$file\" 2>&1`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the error output from cleartool is not coming out on Standard Output (stdout).  With any luck, it's coming out on Standard Error (stderr).  If so, this should work:

```
system "cleartool uncheckout -rm -cact \"$file\" 2>&1";
```

Comment: Yes, I think this was exactly it! adding the stderr makes it parse correctly, so it must have been going there. perfect